# Display live debug messages while running a function in PHP with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, debugging

I have a function like this that may run for 20 minutes:

```
function  test($videoarray)
{
    for($i;$i<100;$i++)
        if(converVideo($videoarray[$i]))
        {
           echo 'video number '.$i.' has been convert';
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'video number '.$i.' Is too large.';
        } 
}
```

During this time I wish I could see the messages live, for example with Ajax/PHP.

Is it possible?

Desired result:

```
1st min:  video number 1 has been converted.
2nd min:  video number 2 is too large.
,
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding `flush();` after each `echo`

This should *force* the message to the screen once written.

Example

```
echo 'video number '.$i.' has been convert';
flush();
```

[**PHP FLUSH**](http://php.net/flush)

This might not always work therefore one can always persist the messages to a database and have a polling mechanism to read the message every couple of seconds.

**[EXAMPLE of PHP Polling](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/polling-database-using-jquery-ajax)**